# error in python recursive code, to find palindromic primes in user inputted interval

Tags: python

I have written a recursive Python program which I have attached below, which prints out the palindromic primes in an interval. I cannot use loops(this is a rule of the assignment). it works fine until I get to large intervals.

here is my code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)

#this function places all the numbers between the start and end points into a list and determines whether they are prime numbers by seeing if they have a remainder of 0 when divided, else numbers that dont have remainder of zero are stored.
def check_prime(num_list,number): 
    if num_list==[]:
        print(number)
    else:
        num=num_list[0]        
        if number % num == 0: # if there is a no remainder then not a prime
            pass
        else:
            num_list.pop(0)
            check_prime(num_list,number)

# this checks whether the numbers in the interval are palindromes by comparing the first 'letter' to the last 'letter' for each number and seeing whether they match.
def check_palindrome(nums):
    nums1=nums[::-1]
    if nums1==nums:
        new_list=list(range(2,int(nums)))
        check_prime(new_list,int(nums))

# this takes both functions and only stores the numbers that match in both functions.
def check_done(lists):
    if lists!=[]: # takes numbers not stored (so the numbers that are palindromes and primes)
        check_palindrome(str(lists[0]))
        lists.pop(0)
        check_done(lists)

start_int=int(input("Enter the starting point N: \n"))
ending_int=int(input("Enter the ending point M: \n"))
palindromic_primes = print("The palindromic primes are:") 
list1=list(range(start_int,ending_int+1)) #the list will analyse all numbers from the start point till the end point
check_done(list1)
```

when entered to (starting point 10000 and ending point 20000) wing IDE i get the following error:

[evaluate palindromeprimes.py]
Enter the starting point N:
10000
Enter the ending point M:
20000
The palindromic primes are:aborted (disconnected)

when I enter it into my schools automaker i get this

```
Comparing output

Output not correct

The expected output was:
Enter the starting point N:
Enter the ending point M:
The palindromic primes are:
10301
10501
10601
11311
11411
12421
12721
12821
13331
13831
13931
14341
14741
15451
15551
16061
16361
16561
16661
17471
17971
18181
18481
19391
19891
19991

Your program produced:
Enter the starting point N: 
Enter the ending point M: 
Segmentation fault

Input supplied to your program:
10000
20000


Differences in the files are as follows:
1,29c1,3
```

according to a tutor, Apparently, i need to make my code more efficient, but I'm not sure how to go about this. I saw told to think of the properties of prime numbers and factors, such as the fact that prime numbers are all odd. Factors occur in pairs, so if the number has no factors before some 'midpoint' then it wont have any after that 'midpoint' either. however i have no idea what they mean by this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursion to iterate through the range of number by spliting that range in two and adding the left and right side results together

When you get to a single value range, you process it to check that it is a palindrome (faster than checking if it is prime) and use recursion to check if it is also a prime number.

You can check for primality recursively by passing a divisor as a defaulted parameter.  The first iteration can check if the number is divisible by 2, then recurse to check if it is divisible by 3, 5, 7, 9 ... (odd numbers).  Once your divisor is greater than the square root of your number, then you know that it is a prime number and a palindrome.  This ends the recursion and returns the number as a one element list (which will be added to the others by the recursive iteration over the range of numbers)

```
def paloPrimes(first,last,prime=2):
    # recursive iteration from first ro last
    if first<last: 
        mid = (first+last)//2
        return paloPrimes(first,mid) + paloPrimes(mid+1,last)
    # now only have one value to check
    if prime==2: # check palindrome 
        if first < 11 or str(first) != str(first)[::-1]: return []
    if first%prime == 0: return []  # not a prime
    if prime*prime < first: 
        return paloPrimes(first,first,prime+1+prime%2) # recurse for primality
    return [first] # return palindromic prime number
```

output:

```
print(paloPrimes(10000,20000))

[10301, 10501, 10601, 11311, 11411, 12421, 12721, 12821, 13331, 13831, 13931, 14341, 14741, 15451, 15551, 16061, 16361, 16561, 16661, 17471, 17971, 18181, 18481, 19391, 19891, 19991]
```

There is a limit to the recursion depth in Python so the size of the range and the magnitude of the numbers will be constrained (e.g. `paloPrimes(3998992,3998994)`)  This function will use a depth of roughly log2(last-first) + √(last/2)